# Show selected option from database in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am a newbie in laravel.
In my database, I have two tables, News(id, id_type) and Type(idtype,name). And in post News page, I use dropdown to select Type for my new news.
So, when I want to show the type name of this News, I do:

```
<div class="controls">
            <select multiple name="Type">
            @foreach($type as $type)
                <option 
                     @if($news->id_type == $type->idtype)
                        selected="selected"
                    @endif 
                value="{{$type->idtype}}">{{$type->name}}</option>
            @endforeach

            </select>
          </div>
```

But I have wrong result for all type in Type tables. 
Help me,please and thanks for your help!!

Comment: Please provide the code snippet of your respective Controller's method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The single equals is for **assignment** while two equals is for **comparison**.  Change this line to be

```
@if($news->id_type == $type->idtype)
```

Answer (score 0):

The code block within `@foreach` can be modified to serve the purpose of selecting a news type corresponding to each news.

```
<select name="Type" id="Type" class="form-control">                                                                  
  @foreach($type AS $data)
     <option value="{{ $data->idtype }}">{{ $data->name }}
     </option>                                                                                               
  @endforeach
</select>
```

The `@if` codeblock is not working as you think it is supposed to. So, better remove it.

Now if you want to get the type associated with each news then you can very well specify it in your Controller and get the news as per the `type_id`.

Code snippet from your Controller will be more helpful.